# fs returns undefined after array.foreach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, return, fs

I am trying to read a file using the fs library then replace some elements after an iteration then return the composed string
However, the function returns undefined

```
function concatproduce(order, producestring) {
    if (order.cart.produce[0].productid != null) {
        order.cart.produce.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (!element.delstatus) {
                element.delstatus = 'Pending';
            }
            fs.readFile('controllers/ordercartitemtemplate.html', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log('lima' + err);
                }
                //console.log(data)
                producestring += (data
                    .replace('//Filename//', element.imageURL)
                    .replace('//Prodname//', element.producename)
                    .replace('//Quantity//', element.quantity)
                    .replace('//Price//', element.price)
                    .replace('//Total//', element.total)
                    .replace('//Delstatus//', element.delstatus));
            });
        });
        return producestring;
    }
}
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous. So, the callback of  `fs.readFile` will not invoke before the `return producestring` is executed that why it always returns undefined. I advise you take time to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&ab_channel=JSConf or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you, I changed the asynchronous file read operation to a synchronous one and also replaced the `forEach` with `reduce`

The function iterates through each of the `produce` elements using [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), refer to the documentation link provided. The `readFileAsync` is used to make it easy to handle the result of the file read and assign it to the `producestring` after each iteration.

```
function concatproduce(order, producestring) {
    if (order.cart.produce[0].productid != null) {
        return order.cart.produce.reduce((producestring, element) => {
            if (!element.delstatus) {
                element.delstatus = 'Pending';
            }
            try {
                const data = fs.readFileSync('controllers/ordercartitemtemplate.html', 'utf8')
                producestring += (data
                    .replace('//Filename//', element.imageURL)
                    .replace('//Prodname//', element.producename)
                    .replace('//Quantity//', element.quantity)
                    .replace('//Price//', element.price)
                    .replace('//Total//', element.total)
                    .replace('//Delstatus//', element.delstatus));
                    return producestring;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('lima' + err);
                return producestring;
            }
        }, producestring);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver... I want to understand your function though... this is like an iteration that returns a value after every iteration?? and then concatenates it to the one in the previous iteration... Did I understand this right??

Comment: I updated the answer, Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I just added an explanation with links in the above answer. The method remains the same.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through the video again but this function worked.